# Number of events fired accumulates with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following problem where the number of events fired by an element keeps accumulating.  The following function `saveList()` is trigged by button press:

```
function saveList(data)
{
    var cnt = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
    {
        perform_XMLHTTPRequest_Action(data[i].imgURL, function(result)
        {
            ...//some action done here
            cnt++;
            if(cnt >= data.length)
            {
                var savedList_ready = new Event('savedlist_ready');
                var page = document.getElementById('page-2');
                page.dispatchEvent(savedList_ready);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then somewhere else another function is called upon picking up an event.  The listeners are as follow:

```
$(document).on('tap', 'button2', function(){
    getData(callBack, onError);
})
```

The `saveList()` function is called by `callBack()`.

```
function callBack(data){
    saveList(data);
    $(document).on('savedList_ready', '#page-2', function(){
        ...
    });
}
```

What I realised is, the number of events fired by `saveList()` is accumulating with the number of button press.  For example, when I press the button2 for the 5th time, 5 events will be fired all at once.  Is there something I can do to limit the number of events to one?  If not, how would you suggest I approach the problem? (every object in data has property imageUrl that requires update via ajax).

Thanks in advance,
Ken

Comment: disable button if you already pressed it

Comment: how is the saveList function attached to the button click event?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, that's not an option for my app, since the button is expected to be clicked many times.

Comment: Sam Bauwens, the saveList function is actually one of the functions that gets called when the button is pressed, after 'data' is obtained via another function.

Comment: Please provide some more details about the click event attachment and handling. What the saveList() method actually does is not relevant for the question/answer (unless it of cause attaches another eventListener ;), if it really gets called multiple times after several clicks. Maybe create a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: This is a typical case of trigger initialisation inside a trigger handler. There must be something in your `savedList_ready` that attaches an `.click()` on something. ex : `$('#one').click(function(){ /* some stuff */ $('#two').click(function(){ ....`  Each time 'one' is clicked, a new event handler is attached to 'two'

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.  I've edited my post and added the listeners.  I though about multiple listener attachments too.  but I believe the code as it is listens for the event(s) that propagate up, and is not attaching a listener to any particular elements?

Comment: Thank you very much @Sam Bauwens and everyone! I just realized my mistake as I edit my answer....the listener was attached every single time in callBack().

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button when clicked

```
$(document).on('tap', 'button2', function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    getData(callBack, onError);
})
```

and re-enable it when the callback is called

```
function callBack(data){
    saveList(data);
    $(document).on('savedList_ready', '#page-2', function(){
         $('button2').prop('disabled',false);
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  After realising what caused the error (and a very dumb mistake it was) I was able to get around it with $(document).off().on(event, function(){});